# Checkbox only changes value when clicked twice

Tags: reactjs

As title says, I set up a checkbox which has the issue that I need to click on it twice to change it's state

The first time I click it behaves as expected, but every attempt after that requires double clicking.

```
state = {
    notification: true,
};

handleInputChange= (event) => {
//I use event.target to operate since I'm trying to set up multiple checkboxes
    this.setState({ [event.target.id]: !event.target.checked });
};

<AppSwitch
  checked={this.state.notification}
  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
  className={"mx-1 switch-color"}
  color={"success"}
  variant={"pill"}
  id="notification"
  name="notification"
/>
```

Comment: do console log you will see that every time its event.target.checked have the same value.

Comment: Does event.target.checked return whether or not the checkbox is checked? If so, then you don't need to ! it. `this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.checked });`

Comment: I did, that's when I realized it only changes value after I click twice. It outputs something like "true > false > false > true > true > false > false > true" and so on with every click.

Comment: @jvgaeta that did the trick, but I don't understand why. Mind if I ask you to elaborate a bit on why it works that way?

Comment: Can you share source link for AppSwitch ?

Comment: @Bahtiyar it's a component taken from a CoreUI template.

Comment: this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.checked });  is it working ? it should work

Comment: It's because event.target.checked returns whether the checkbox is checked. So, if you check it, it returns true and if you uncheck it, it returns false. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, I understand. I thought it returned the current value of the checkbox based on `this.state.notification`, there's the confusion. If you want to post this as an answer I'll verify it, thank you!

Comment: yes it is true. if switch is checked , it should returns true . if switch is unchecked , it should returns false ,that means ,switch is unchecked..  When handleInputChange is fired , set state  notification is checked (true) or unchecked (false)

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to ! when you're setting state here. It should be `this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.checked });`, since `event.target.checked` returns the checked state of the checkbox. So, if you click the checkbox and it transitions to checked, then it will be true. Then, if you click the checkbox and it transitions to unchecked then it will be false.